# How to add a control bone to my rig?

Tags: animation, armature

I already have my character rigged but I am wondering how to add a control bone to control the same thing because in the NLA editor I cannot make my character walk and animate at the same time.

Here is my file http://www.filedropper.com/rigtest_1

Comment: link to the file with my rig http://www.filedropper.com/rigtest_1

Comment: what do you mean by "control the same thing"?